# Restlet Standalone Application Limitations

Tags: java, performance, web-services, web-applications, restlet

So I have 3 different process which should be run independently. So right now these 3 are java projects. To communicate with each other I am currently using restlet standalone server and client.

So my question is, is it OK to have these 3 servers running on different ports and communicate with each other using restlet clients. Will this scenario work on production where there will be hundreds of calls. How many calls it can handle?

Also is this scenario better or the one where I convert all these java projects into web application and host them on tomcat.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restlet Framework can perfectly support this use case. If the standalone/internal HTTP connectors reach some scalability limitation in your case, you can easily plug-in the Jetty connectors as a more robust solution without changing a line of code.

Note that you can also listen on multiple ports at the same time in a single Restlet application and communicate inside the JVM using the Restlet RIAP pseudo-protocol.